# how to create SSRS report subscription with two different parameter selection data for the same report?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, parameters, subscription

I have a new requirement with SSRS reporting. i have an SQL query with two parameters which are start and end date. the requirement is i want to create subscription for the report to be sent to particular email on weekly basis. the report should be sent as an excel file with two worksheets. first sheet should have the data from the parameter value selected as 'Startdate=getdate-7 and enddate=getdate()' and the second sheet should have the data from the parameter value selected as 'Startdate=oct-18-2019 and endate=getdate()'. Could anyone help me how to achieve this? i know we can create two separate reports and send two different subscriptions for this. but not sure if we can acheive this sending this in one suscription. or you can also help me if this can be sent in one email subscription but with two different excel sheets.

Answer (score 0):

You can do 1 report with 2 Data-Driven Subscriptions.

Click [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/subscriptions/data-driven-subscriptions?view=sql-server-ver15) for documentation

Check [Here](https://jackworthen.com/2016/05/06/creating-a-data-driven-subscription-in-sql-server-reporting-services/) for a good article with a clear examples

[image]

Comment: Did you try to do a subscription?

Comment: Any news about it?